# What is the version directive for?

Tags: docker-compose

I've read through the docs at: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/ and find no reference to a directive that seems to be present in all sample `docker-compose.yml` files I've seen, namely the `version`

is that meant to indicate the version of docker-compose to be used? or is it an arbitrary version number I can assign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the version in the docker-compose file is describing the Compose file formats and is linked to specific docker engine versions.
More info can be found just couple links lower from what you found:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/

You cannot specify whatever you want, the current options are: 3.1, 3.0, 2.1, 2.0, 1.0.

Each version is also add or deprecating options and enables new docker engine capabilities to be used like `swarm` in v3.